# In ASP.NET what makes Owin Middleware execute before authenticate?

Tags: asp.net, owin

I find documentation that says in order for Owin Middleware to execute before stage 10, there must be an explicit call to

```
 app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline

In the current projects scaffolded with Visual Studio 2015 (4.5), I can't find any call like that in the startup.cs yet it seems to execute before authenticate.

Can someone explain what causes owin pipeline to execute before auth and not at stage 10 like the doc suggests?